# NSLayoutConstraint, sub-viewing a UIView in a table view cell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

So I am using a project that I found on Github — https://github.com/kmonaghan/CBPWordPress — and am trying to get a handle on it.

Essentially, what I want to do is create the floating "Cards" illusion that an app like Facebook has. The way that I have accomplished this in the past is by creating a subview UIView, rounding the corners, etc. before putting the title label, author name inside of that view. The issue is that I have typically done that with storyboards, while this example programmatically lays things out.

After toying around with it, I thought I had figured it out. This is how I set up the -(void)updateConstraints method:

- (void)updateConstraints
  {
  if (!self.constraintsUpdated) {

  ```
  self.contentView.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CBPLargePostPreviewTableViewCellHeight);

  NSDictionary *views = @{@"postCommentLabel": self.postCommentLabel,
                          @"postDateLabel": self.postDateLabel,
                          @"postImageView": self.postImageView,
                          @"postTitleLabel": self.postTitleLabel,
                          @"roundedBackground": self.roundedBackground};

  NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding": @(CBPPadding)};

  [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(4)-[roundedBackground]-(4)-|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:metrics
                                                                                   views:views]];
  [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(4)-[roundedBackground]-(4)-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:metrics
                                                                             views:views]];

  [self.roundedBackground addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(5)-[postTitleLabel]-(5)-[postImageView(150)]-(5)-[postDateLabel]-(5)-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];
  [self.roundedBackground addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(padding)-[postTitleLabel]-(padding)-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:metrics
                                                                             views:views]];
  [self.roundedBackground addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(padding)-[postImageView]-(padding)-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:metrics
                                                                             views:views]];
  [self.roundedBackground addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(padding)-[postDateLabel]-(>=0)-[postCommentLabel]-(padding)-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:metrics
                                                                             views:views]];
  [self.roundedBackground addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.postCommentLabel
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.postDateLabel
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              multiplier:1.0f
                                                                constant:0]];

  self.constraintsUpdated = YES;
  }

  [super updateConstraints];
  }
  ```

But upon running I get this error: [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[4]'

I have tried creating bounds for the view, but to no avail. Does anybody have any suggestions? If there is a better approach to creating the effect I am looking for, I am also open to that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use **roundedBackground** in visual format strings, but have **background**
key in your views dict.

Comment: Sorry about that (I changed some of the code when I copy / pasted it, not a good idea). Nonetheless, even when correct, I still get the error I described.